# Assigning a different keyboard shortcut per opened application in Windows

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I have two opened Windows applications in Windows 7 which I would like to switch between them using a single keyboard shortcut, either one key to switch between them or a separate key for each. Basically instead of clicking the app icon on the taskbar, to do it through a keyboard hotkey.

How can this be done? I don't want to use alt-tab to switch because I have several other opened apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have them on your Windows taskbar you can easily switch to them using:

<kbd>Windows</kbd> +  <kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>2</kbd>

(given that they are the most left icons on your taskbar)

Comment: Another solution is using AutoHotKey, but I'll leave it to John T to tell you how to do so